# pyenv on Mojave throwing undeclared identifier 'CLOCK_REALTIME' and other errors when installing 3.5.6, 3.6.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, macos-mojave, pyenv

I'm trying to install various versions of python3 on macOS Mojave `10.14.2 Beta (18C52a)`.

#### 3.6.7 fails with:

```
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.6.7.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.7/Python-3.6.7.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.6.7...
python-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.2 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/db/pjnyydt54kl3_snfwpvlsxf40000gp/T/python-build.20181204115752.83999
Results logged to /var/folders/db/pjnyydt54kl3_snfwpvlsxf40000gp/T/python-build.20181204115752.83999.log

Last 10 log lines:
./Include/pytime.h:200:52: warning: declaration of 'struct tm' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
PyAPI_FUNC(int) _PyTime_localtime(time_t t, struct tm *tm);
                                                   ^
./Include/pytime.h:204:49: warning: declaration of 'struct tm' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
PyAPI_FUNC(int) _PyTime_gmtime(time_t t, struct tm *tm);
                                                ^
2 warnings generated.
2 warnings generated.
2 warnings generated.
2 warnings generated.
```

#### 3.5.6 fails with:

```
python-build: use openssl from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.5.6.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.6/Python-3.5.6.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.5.6...
python-build: use readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.2 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/db/pjnyydt54kl3_snfwpvlsxf40000gp/T/python-build.20181204115931.92145
Results logged to /var/folders/db/pjnyydt54kl3_snfwpvlsxf40000gp/T/python-build.20181204115931.92145.log

Last 10 log lines:
Python/pytime.c:508:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'clock_getres' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        if (clock_getres(CLOCK_REALTIME, &res) == 0)
            ^
Python/pytime.c:508:13: warning: this function declaration is not a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
Python/pytime.c:508:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'CLOCK_REALTIME'
        if (clock_getres(CLOCK_REALTIME, &res) == 0)
                         ^
4 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [Python/pytime.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

---

I've tried, through `brew`:

1. Reinstalling all of `pyenv`, `python`, `python3`, `xz`, `readline`, `openssl` (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51551598/1214800))
2. I've tried installing and reinstalling the macOS developer tools
3. I've tried `sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /` (per the pyenv docs)
4. I tried this on a new build of Mojave running `10.14.1 (18B75)`, and I get the same problem.

Oh, and darn, I’m using Fish. I’ll have to look and see if this is a Fish-specific problem  
(Update: no, it's not Fish, it happens in a standard `/bin/sh`)

Comment: Did you try install pyenv from source, via Github to see if that works? https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout . Also do you have the most up to date version of gcc & xcode installed?

Comment: Have not tried building from source, I’ll give it a shot. Also better double check which Xcode version is active... good call.

Comment: No worries, keep me in the loop, want to see how this turns out :)

Comment: Not a specific solution to your problem; I had the same issue when trying to install python 2, I worked around it by installing a version of miniconda2.

Comment: Could you post the complete log file please?

Comment: I think we're onto something here with fish, but even then I'm not totally sure. I can't even get it to work with fish's goofy non-standard path/syntax variables, but even then, if others are having the problem too...

Comment: And now, I just tried it with asdf, and the _same_ error occurs.

Comment: @Tiger-222 https://pastebin.com/4W5nr8tJ

Answer (score 0):

If you would and to maintain different versions of python, [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf) is a good option. You could use the following steps to install.

```
git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.6.2
```

And since you seem to using fish you could do the following

```
echo 'source ~/.asdf/asdf.fish' >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish
mkdir -p ~/.config/fish/completions; and cp ~/.asdf/completions/asdf.fish ~/.config/fish/completions
```

At this point you would want relaunch your terminal for the asdf to take effect. One mac OS you might need to homebrew install `coreutils automake autoconf openssl libyaml readline libxslt libtool unixodbc`, as some the plugin might need them.

Then you are now set to install python plugin. First need to pull it it.

```
asdf plugin-add python
```

Once you have the plugin installed it is time to install your needed versions.

```
asdf install python 3.5.6
asdf install python 3.6.7
```

Once they are intalled successfully, you could switch between them using

```
asdf global python <version-of-your-choice: eg. 3.5.6>
```

eg.
    asdf global python 3.5.6

I hope this helps.

Comment: There seem to issues reported on this, [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue22287) and [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue30183)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this was the problem, but I ran into a similar error when I was trying to install a number of pip packages that had a build step which relied on `time.h`. The problem was that I had a stray one deficient in the necessary exports inside `/usr/local/include`. If you're (mis)using brew, you might have a number of redundant, out of date, and conflicting headers/libs linked in `/usr/local/*`. I suggest getting a verbose output, find the exact build command that produces the error, look at each `-I` flag, and search recursively for `time.h`. My bet is that one of them is some relic you want to get rid of.