# pyenv install 3.8.0b4 on macOS Mojave

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyenv

I am trying to install the latest beta version of the new Python 3.8.
My laptop is running macOS Mojave.
I am following the tutorial on RealPython:
https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/

and have skimmed through similar questions, e.g. [pyenv 3.6.5 BUILD FAILED macOS Mojave 10.14.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194588/pyenv-3-6-5-build-failed-macos-mojave-10-14-5)

First I run the commands:

```sh
brew install openssl readline sqlite3 xz zlib
sudo installer -pkg /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg -target /
curl https://pyenv.run | bash
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
$ exec "$SHELL"
pyenv install --list | grep " 3\.[8]"
```

Which run successfully and shows that Python 3.8.0b4 is the latest release, which I wish to install;

When attempting to install with:

```sh
pyenv install 3.8.0b4
```

The result reads:

```sh
-bash: pyenv: command not found
```

pyenv is installed however. Any idea about why the command isn't found?

(See the BASH terminal below).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [PyEnv BUILD FAILED installing Python on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551557/pyenv-build-failed-installing-python-on-macos)

The below command successfully installed Python 3.8.0b4:

```sh
SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.14 pyenv install 3.8.0b4
```

See output below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote in the description was different with what you typed in the shell.

According to the screenshot, `pyenv` was **not initialized** yet before python installation, which means command `pyenv` was not added into `PATH` and the sub-commands were not available either.

You'd better write the init scripts into your bash configuration file, like `~/.bashrc`

```sh
export PATH="$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"

if command -v pyenv &>/dev/null; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
if command -v pyenv-virtualenv &>/dev/null; then
  eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
fi
```

After that, start a new shell and do the Python installation.

You can check the `README.md` at the project's repo on GitHub for more info.