# Installation of python 3.8 fails with pyenv on macOS

Tags: python, pyenv

Installing python 3.8.8 with `pyenv` is failing.

The installation fails as follows:

```
$pyenv install 3.8.8
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.8.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.8/Python-3.8.8.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.8...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.7 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/d6/m67jyndd7h754m3810cl3bpm0000gp/T/python-build.20210323082704.55952
Results logged to /var/folders/d6/m67jyndd7h754m3810cl3bpm0000gp/T/python-build.20210323082704.55952.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking for python3.8... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/d6/m67jyndd7h754m3810cl3bpm0000gp/T/python-build.20210323082704.55952/Python-3.8.8':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

I am on *Catalina* with the latest *xcode* installed

```
$/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
Xcode 12.4
Build version 12D4e
```

*gcc* looks reasonable:

```
$which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

$gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Here is info on `clang`:

```
$which clang
/usr/bin/clang
09:17:36/Python-3.8.8 $clang -v
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

**Update** Here are some errors in the `config.log`: there are complaints about *clang* :

```
configure:3869: clang -V >&5
clang: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang: error: no input files
configure:3880: $? = 1
configure:3869: clang -qversion >&5
clang: error: unknown argument '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
clang: error: no input files

...

configure:3922: clang -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk  -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/Users/steve/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include-isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/Users/steve/.pyenv/versions/3.8.8/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib conftest.c  >&5
clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk-isysroot' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/opt/local/lib'
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Note that I have looked through the answers at [PyEnv BUILD FAILED installing Python on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551557/pyenv-build-failed-installing-python-on-macos) .  For example I tried the following:

```
export SDKROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.15
pyenv install 3.8.8
```

But it failed the same way.  What else should I check and how might this be resolved?

Comment: Anything useful in `config.log` ?

Comment: Interestingly, I am also on 10.15.7 and `gcc -v` (which really just is an alias for `clang`, i think) points to `Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)`, yet I'm able to install 3.8 with pyenv just fine.

Comment: @BradSolomon where is the _config.log_ actually?  I had looked for it but it's not in the current working directory

Comment: Maybe a `find /var/folders/d6/m67jyndd7h754m3810cl3bpm0000gp/T/python-build.20210323082704* -name '*.log' -type f` ?

Comment: Yes you're right. looking through the _config.log_ now