# PyEnv BUILD installing Python on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

While trying to install Python 3.7.7  using PyEnv on MacOS, I am encountering build failure.

```
BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.5.2 using python-build 20180424)
Inspect or clean up the working tree at 
/var/folders/qp/vtg2pn3n7bj4lxx5dlj6sx3m0000gn/T/
python-build.20210825120858.1864
Results logged to /var/folders/qp/
vtg2pn3n7bj4lxx5dlj6sx3m0000gn/T/
python-build.20210825120858.1864.log
```

I've tried some solutions but none of them work ([example] ([PyEnv BUILD FAILED installing Python on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551557/pyenv-build-failed-installing-python-on-macos)))

Environment / Framework versions

MacOS Big Sur 11.5.2